# Vite/Vue3 throws Internal server error (experimental syntax / missing parser plugin: decorators) after upgrade

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vite

After updating Vite I can't start my project anymore because I get the following error message:

`[vite] Internal server error: This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): "decorators-legacy","decorators"`

Before the update everything was running without problems and also the log doesn't really help me.
I use SFC in Vue and vue-class-component and vue-property-decorator for my components.

I have updated:

```
vite: 2.6.14 -> 2.9.12
@vitejs/plugin-vue: 1.8.0 -> 2.3.3
@vue/compiler-sfc: 3.2.22 -> removed, because it is now a part of plugin-vue
```

The problem occurs with both the "vite" and "vite build" scripts.
The errors it finds seem to occur mainly in the  part of the components:

```
// Log

12:55:04 [vite] Internal server error: This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): "decorators-legacy", "decorators". (7:2)
  Plugin: vite:vue
  File: A:/repositories/private/scribe/src/components/app/ui/tooltip/Tooltip.vue
  6  |      <div
  7  |        class="tooltip"
  8  |        :class="{
     |      ^
  9  |          'tooltip--show': show,
  10 |          'tooltip--left': isLeft,
12:55:06 [vite] Internal server error: This experimental syntax requires enabling one of the following parser plugin(s): "decorators-legacy", "decorators". (21:2)
  Plugin: vite:vue
  File: A:/repositories/private/scribe/src/components/app/ui/dropdown/Dropdown.vue
  9  |        :class="{
  10 |          'dropdown-list--expanded': open,
  11 |          'dropdown-list--wide': wide,
     |                                     ^
  12 |          'dropdown-list--expanded-top': open && top,
  13 |        }"
```

These are the dependencies currently installed:

```
// package.json

...

  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "3.6.9",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "3.0.0-5",
    "@samuelmeuli/font-manager": "1.4.0",
    "@tiptap/extension-font-family": "2.0.0-beta.24",
    "@tiptap/extension-image": "2.0.0-beta.30",
    "@tiptap/extension-link": "2.0.0-beta.42",
    "@tiptap/extension-text-align": "2.0.0-beta.31",
    "@tiptap/extension-text-style": "2.0.0-beta.26",
    "@tiptap/extension-underline": "2.0.0-beta.25",
    "@tiptap/starter-kit": "2.0.0-beta.189",
    "@tiptap/vue-3": "2.0.0-beta.95",
    "@types/he": "1.1.2",
    "@vue/apollo-composable": "4.0.0-alpha.18",
    "@vuelidate/core": "2.0.0-alpha.41",
    "@vuelidate/validators": "2.0.0-alpha.29",
    "click-outside-vue3": "4.0.1",
    "core-js": "3.23.2",
    "crypto-js": "4.1.1",
    "date-fns": "2.28.0",
    "dompurify": "2.3.8",
    "downloadjs": "1.4.7",
    "graphql": "16.5.0",
    "graphql-tag": "2.12.6",
    "he": "1.2.0",
    "html2canvas": "1.4.1",
    "jsonpack": "1.1.5",
    "localforage": "1.10.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.21",
    "mitt": "3.0.0",
    "object-hash": "3.0.0",
    "prismjs": "1.28.0",
    "register-service-worker": "1.7.2",
    "splitpanes": "3.1.1",
    "typogr": "0.6.8",
    "vite-plugin-markdown": "2.0.2",
    "vue": "3.2.37",
    "vue-class-component": "8.0.0-rc.1",
    "vue-color-kit": "1.0.5",
    "vue-gtag": "2.0.1",
    "vue-i18n": "9.1.10",
    "vue-prism-editor": "2.0.0-alpha.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "10.0.0-rc.3",
    "vue-router": "4.0.16",
    "vue-scrollto": "2.20.0",
    "vue-waypoint": "4.2.1",
    "vuedraggable": "4.1.0",
    "vuex": "4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n": "3.4.0",
    "@intlify/vue-i18n-loader": "4.2.0",
    "@types/crypto-js": "4.1.1",
    "@types/dompurify": "2.3.3",
    "@types/downloadjs": "1.4.3",
    "@types/jsonpack": "1.1.1",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.182",
    "@types/object-hash": "2.2.1",
    "@types/prismjs": "1.26.0",
    "@types/splitpanes": "2.2.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.29.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.29.0",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "2.3.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "7.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "11.0.0",
    "eslint": "8.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "9.1.1",
    "lint-staged": "13.0.2",
    "prettier": "2.7.1",
    "sass": "1.53.0",
    "sass-loader": "13.0.0",
    "typescript": "4.7.4",
    "vite": "2.9.12",
    "vite-plugin-commonjs": "0.5.2",
    "vite-plugin-i18n-resources": "1.0.3",
    "vite-plugin-package-version": "1.0.2",
    "vue-tsc": "0.38.1"
  },
```

My Typescript configuration:

```
// tsconfig.json

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ],
    "types": [
      "@intlify/vite-plugin-vue-i18n/client"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "./src/types",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

And my Vite configuration:

```
// vite.config.json

import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
import loadVersion from "vite-plugin-package-version";
import i18nResources from "vite-plugin-i18n-resources";
import markdown, { Mode } from "vite-plugin-markdown";
import { resolve } from "path";

const path = require("path")

function graphQlFile() {
  return {
    name: 'graphql-file',
    transform(src, id) {
      if (id.endsWith(".graphql") || id.endsWith(".gql")) {
        const str = JSON.stringify(src)
        return {
          code: "import gql from 'graphql-tag';const doc="+str+"; export default gql`${doc}`",
          map: null
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

export const ssrTransformCustomDirective = () => {
  return {
    props: [],
    needRuntime: true
  }
}

export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 8080
  },
    resolve: {
    alias: [
      {
        find: "@",
        replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, "src")
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    vue({
      template: {
        ssr: true,
        compilerOptions: {
          directiveTransforms: {
            "click-outside": ssrTransformCustomDirective,
            "safe-html": ssrTransformCustomDirective
          }
        }
      }
    }),
    i18nResources({
      path: resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    }),
    loadVersion(),
    graphQlFile(),
    markdown({ mode: Mode.HTML })
  ]
})
```

Comment: Did you happen to solve this yet? Just noticed the same thing myself, but downgraded a few dependencies here and there, yet the error didn't go away.
(and yes, I did nuke `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` in between)

Comment: @Dids Not yet. I will let you know i solve it.

Comment: Do you happen to be on an M1 Mac by any chance? Because I've reverted every dependency, Node.js and Vite/TypeScript config change since it last 100% worked, and it's still throwing the same error. But now I got to thinking, because the last time I worked on this, I was on an Intel Mac, while I'm now on an M1 Mac.

EDIT: Never mind, tried it on a CI and it still fails. I'm stumped.

Comment: This has now been fixed in Vue, see my updated answer below.

Answer (score 1):

## LATEST UPDATE - 18.8.2022

**The issue has now been fixed in Vue!**

You can find the pull request for the fix [here](https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/6320).

---

**NOTE: The information below is out of date, see the update at the top, as well as the progress updates below!**

Found a solution to this particular error, but do note that this is only a partial solution, at least for now.
At the time of writing this, you need to use Vite's pre-release builds, which fix the issue.

In my case, I only had to update the following dependencies:

```
"@vitejs/plugin-vue": "3.0.0-beta.1",
"vite": "^3.0.0-beta.7",
```

You may run into issues trying to install these, as there are version requirements on other packages that do not allow Vite's 3.x package to be installed, in which case you can simply run the following:

```
rm -fr node_modules package-lock.json
npm install --force
```

After this, you should be able to both build and run with Vite, without it (or Babel) complaining about the decorators.

The bad news is that you may run into other, new errors after this, which I suppose need to be fixed in Vite and all the plugins that utilize it/which you need for your particular project.

---

**UPDATE - 21.7.2022**

The issue seems to be coming from Vue's single-file-component (SFC) compiler, and there's now an open issue in their GitHub Repository:
https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/6318

Additionally, the same person seems to have worked out a pull request that fixes the issue, which is still open here:
https://github.com/vuejs/core/pull/6320

Judging by the issue and pull request above, the issue we're seeing seems to be explicitly caused by using decorators before `export default ...`, which does not get rewritten/transpiled correctly, causing this issue.

Right now we'd either need to wait, make the changes locally or fork our own copy and apply the pull request's fixes, then use our forked version of the SFC compiler. Fingers crossed, this should fix it for good!

**EDIT:** I tried the fix and can confirm that it works! Below is my how I applied it to my project for now, in case you (or anyone else) wants to try it).

Changes to `package.json`:

```json
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "npm run patch-vue-compiler-sfc",
  "patch-vue-compiler-sfc": "patch --ignore-whitespace -p0 --forward < vue-compiler-sfc.patch || true"
}
```

Create a new patch file called `vue-compiler-sfc.patch` with the following contents:

```
--- node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js.orig    2022-08-02 12:54:51
+++ node_modules/@vue/compiler-sfc/dist/compiler-sfc.cjs.js 2022-08-02 16:10:06
@@ -3352,7 +3352,12 @@
     }).program.body;
     ast.forEach(node => {
         if (node.type === 'ExportDefaultDeclaration') {
-            s.overwrite(node.start, node.declaration.start, `const ${as} = `);
+            if (node.declaration.type === 'ClassDeclaration') {
+                s.overwrite(node.start, node.declaration.id.start, `class `)
+                s.append(`\nconst ${as} = ${node.declaration.id.name}`)
+            } else {
+                s.overwrite(node.start, node.declaration.start, `const ${as} = `)
+            }
         }
         if (node.type === 'ExportNamedDeclaration') {
             for (const specifier of node.specifiers) {
```

Now simply run `npm i` and the patch will be applied and your project should now be rid of this error, even if as only a temporary solution.

Comment: This only changes my errors. Now i get:
`Decorators can only be used with class declarations in TypeScript` and `[vite] Internal server error: Cannot overwrite across a split point`
I think this is a problem with: `vue-property-decorator` At this point i plan to switch completly to the composition API and hope that everything works than

Comment: See the updated answer, there's light at the end of the tunnel now!

Comment: Updated again, this time with quick instructions on patching the issues locally, with minimal work.

Comment: Hi, I'm not that advanced with patching but i'm getting `patch unexpectedly ends in middle of line` when i run this patch, can you tell me why?

Comment: @Nebulosar You probably just need an empty line at the end of the patch file. I'll edit that in the patch above and make a note of it, good catch!

Comment: Also note that since the SFC package was recently updated, this patch no longer applies to it, so I'll try to fix it and update the answer again with a new patch, although I'm very much hoping the Vue developers would just merge the fix already.

Comment: @Nebulosar Try adding `--ignore-whitespace` to the `patch` command's arguments. I've edited the answer above to reflect this. If this is not enough, the patch file just needs a new line at the end, then it should work.

Comment: I've updated both `package.json` and `vue-sfc-compiler.patch` to now be more verbose, but also more forgiving when patching, eg. line endings and whitespace should no longer matter. Additionally, by utilizing `postinstall` in `package.json`, it will now attempt to apply the patch every time `npm install` is ran.

Comment: Thank you for assisting the noob in me :) Got it working using your guidelines

Comment: This has now been fixed in Vue, see the updated answer.